# Where does prestashop db backup files stored?

Tags: mysql, prestashop

Local prestashop installations (not cloud one) creates backup files from its administration interface. It also let you download them. In which folder does these backup files are located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `adminXXXX` folder and look for `backup`.

1. https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/tree/develop/admin-dev/backups
2. https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/tree/develop/admin-dev/autoupgrade/backup

Comment: Thank you. It helped me to find directory. On my deployment which uses apache as web server, files are under htdocs/administration/backups and htdocs/administration/autoupgrade/backups.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it :).